# Как изменить CSS-свойство на JS?

Tags: javascript

Наверняка вопрос задавался, не знаю как правильно его искать. Вот строка кода на JS:

```
document.getElementById('myid').style.margin-left = values+'%';
```

Ошибка в консоли:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Тире в имени свойства ему видимо не нравится, т.к. просто style.margin работает. Как ему подать на вход названия свойств с тире что бы не было ошибки?

Comment: надо `marginLeft` ... стили, в которых есть прочерк, в js пишутся через camelCase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если css свойство называется через дефис - то указывать его нужно в js так:
Дефис убирается, и каждое слово после дефиса должно называться с большой буквы.

```
margin-left: = marginLeft
```

И так со всеми свойствами которые имеют название с дефисом